# How to pass data from modal to component?

Tags: angular

I have modal component and it looks like this:

```
<z-popup title="User search" #generaldetailHistoryModal modalSize="modal-lg" (onHideModal)="onHideModal()" footer="true"> 
    <div content-type="body"> 
        <z-grid [columns]="columnsUserSearchModal" [data]='users' paginator="true"  (selectedItemClick)='setSelectedUser($event)'></z-grid>
    </div>
</z-popup>
```

I have preview component where i call this modal:

```
<user-search-modal [modalShown]="modalUserSearchShown" (onHide)="modalUserSearchShown=false"></user-search-modal>
```

Now what i want is to pass what i selected in modal to preview component.

In modal.ts i get selected data:

```
  setSelectedUser(event:any){
        this.selectedData.emit(event);
    }
```

But now i dont know how pass that data to preview component?

Comment: See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

Comment: I know how to use emit, here i have component inside  component, and then i need to pass value to third component

Comment: WIth the description you give it sounds like you have to use the @Output and EventEmitter in the modal to pass the data to the preview component, because I understand there is only parent and child, or where is the third component you mention?

Comment: Well at this moment i get data in modal.ts in method setSeletedUser... but im calling modal component inside preview component, so how will i pass that data from setSelectedUser to preview component?

Comment: Because right now with emit i dont get anything

Answer (score 5):

To avoid unnecessary code in the components (keep binding to inputs from the (grand) parent to the child) and because you have said that:

> here i have component inside component, and then i need to pass value to third component

I would [**use a service**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service). Something like this ([working Plunkr example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oy3cBYt00k7eIWZngZpS?p=preview)):

> ***modal.service.ts***
>
> ```
> import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Injectable()
> export class ModalService {
>   public selectedUserChange = new EventEmitter()
> }
> ```
>
> ***The other components (not modularized for simplicity)***
>
> ```
> import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
> import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
> import {ModalService} from './modal.service'
>
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'grand-child',
>   template: `
>     <output *ngIf="user">{{ user }}</output>
>   `,
> })
> export class GrandChildComponent implements OnInit {
>   private user
>
>   constructor(public modalService: ModalService) {
>   }
>   ngOnInit() {
>     this.modalService.selectedUserChange
>       .subscribe((user) => {
>         this.user = user
>       })
>   }
> }
>
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'child-component',
>   template: `
>     <grand-child></grand-child>
>   `,
> })
> export class ChildComponent {
> }
>
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-app',
>   template: `
>     <div>
>       <button (click)="setSelectedUser('bob')">set user to bob</button>
>       <button (click)="setSelectedUser('amy')">set user to amy</button>
>     </div>
>     <child-component></child-component>
>   `,
> })
> export class App {
>
>   constructor(public modalService: ModalService) {
>   }
>
>   setSelectedUser(user){
>     this.modalService.selectedUserChange.emit(user)
>   }
> }
>
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [ BrowserModule ],
>   declarations: [ App, ChildComponent, GrandChildComponent ],
>   providers: [ ModalService ]
>   bootstrap: [ App ]
> })
> export class AppModule {}
> ```